# What is the real story behind movie Badlapur?

Tags: realism, badlapur

During the interviews makers said that Badlapur is based on true events happened in central Europe in 1980s. Some say these events actually happened in Pune itself. Does anybody know the exact real events happened.

Comment: The plot of *Badlapur* is based on Massimo Carlotto's book *Death's Dark Abyss*. Whether the *book* is based on a true story is a mystery to me; all I know is that Carlotto was wrongfully imprisoned himself and [claims](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2006/10/15/AR2006101500884.html) that his stories are based on real life.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It has satisfied a part of my question. But the makers have said (quote) "Badlapur is based on a real-life incident that took place nearly 25 yers ago in Central Europe". Massimo was imprisoned for totally different reason.He must have taken inspiration from some events for this novel. I am looking for those events. Thank you again.

Comment: Almost every entry I see about it says something to the effect of: "*Badlapur is based on a real-life incident that happened decades ago. It's a story of a family man who sets out to take revenge after being wronged.*" It happened in Europe. That's all they are *really* saying. I wonder if it's actually to help sell the movie. As a true to life story, it becomes a human interest thing. People want to know. Because of that, it's usually out there. Since it's not (as far as I can tell), it makes me wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [Reuters interview](http://blogs.reuters.com/india/2015/02/06/a-minute-with-sriram-raghavan/), the director Sriram Raghavan was asked about the film's background:

> Q: What is “Badlapur” based on?
>
> A: Basically it is an account written by a person (author Massimo
>   Carlotto) who spent a lot of time in jail. He’s written quite a few
>   stories, but many of his stories are actually about people he met in
>   prison. The account he wrote is true but it happened elsewhere in the
>   world. But some stories are universal, and I felt that this was a
>   revenge story with a difference.

So although in interviews Raghaven frequently refers to his movie being based on real-life events, it appears he means based on the novel, which itself was supposedly based on real-life events. The implication in Raghavan's quote is that Carlotto met a prisoner whilst behind bars and Raghavan's movie is based on their story.

So now we move on to the key question - whilst Raghavan claims the novel is based on true events, *is it really or is simply fiction?*.

In an interview with [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2005/jan/30/crimebooks.features), Carlotto said:

> 'I have never once made up a killing,' he says. 'Every single death in
>   everything I have written relates to a real killing, one for which I
>   have read the autopsy report. I have seen the documents, I have
>   carried out one-to-one interviews with murderers. This is my way of
>   recording what is happening in present day Italy.
>
> 'The Noir writers talk about the social and political situation right
>   now; they react very quickly to changes in the criminal world. In
>   Italy, Mediterranean Noir is called the literature of reality. I even
>   have journalists calling me when they are writing about crime, to ask
>   me what is going on. The world of journalism has changed. There is no
>   investigation now. Italy has lost any real sense of truth, because
>   nobody believes the official "truths".
>
> 'It is very rare now for crime writers [in Italy] to invent stories.
>   Most of them are real. Only the names are changed. That's why these
>   books are so popular.'

And of course we now reach the problem. With the names changed, and without access to all the various autopsy reports and public records, it's impossible to verify whether the people in the book are actually real, are mostly real with fictional embellishments, or entirely fictional creations of Carlotto.

Carlotto hasn't given any interviews where has has *proven* the events - largely I suspect because he doesn't need to. And whilst the story is riveting, I doubt it's so unique that it would be easy to identify if it had really occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The movie is based on real incidents that happened in 1990. The incident that happened is just known to have happened, there hasn't been an actual recording of the exact events. The film's story, however, follows those events closely, do just watch the film you'll get an idea of what happened. The book *Death's Dark Abyss*, just inspired the movie's theme and overall emotion, not the story.

Comment: Sorry but this does not exactly answer my question; Also, I have reached to a conclusion that movie was entirely based on Death's Dark Abyss (i have read the novel). If the events happened in reality or not must be asked to author (Massimo Carlotto) himself. The "events happened" gimmick was used by makers just to publicize the movie and I don't think they also knew anything about it. Thank you for the response though.